# How can I use a trigger to update several tables taking specific data from rows in a table being updated?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have searched quite a bit and can't seem to find the answer to this. I am fairly new to MySQL and this is something I had previously written as a php script to update the individual tables, but would rather it update automatically on the database when the table changes.

When I update a table via a google script I then require about 6 different tables to be updated from different rows in the main table, by date, and each table requires data from a different column.

I know this is not the correct way to do it but I need the trigger to effectively do the following;

```
CREATE TRIGGER dash_1 
ON global_summary AFTER UPDATE

UPDATE widget_dash_2 (date, metric)
WHERE inc_id=100 SELECT date, volume 
FROM global_summary
WHERE (`date` = SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1))
UPDATE widget_dash_2 (date, metric)
WHERE inc_id=101 SELECT date, volume 
FROM global_summary
WHERE (`date` = SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 8))
```

This would be for one of the columns "volume" from table "global_summary", I then need to add up to another 5 updates such as;

```
UPDATE widget_dash_3 (date, metric)
WHERE inc_id=100 SELECT date, score 
FROM global_summary
WHERE (`date` = SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1))
UPDATE widget_dash_3 (date, metric)
WHERE inc_id=101 SELECT date, score 
FROM global_summary
WHERE (`date` = SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 8))
```

Where "score" is another column in the table "global_summary".

Any guidance would be much appreciated. I have been looking for some guidance on this for days now and it has just made me more confused.

I'm assuming I need to do something with arrays and initially getting all data from the main table, but how can I then carve that up?

@sticky bit,

Unfortunately I have to put this data into these small tables, believe me I would much rather just pull it from global_summary directly.

```
CREATE TABLE `global_summary` (
`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`volume` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`volume_problem` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`removed` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`score` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`error` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`total` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`previous` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`entryID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

All the widget_dash tables;

```
CREATE TABLE `widget_dash_2` (
`inc_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`metric` int(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Thanks for your feedback so far, and yes I probably was confusing UPDATE with INSERT.

Comment: Your `UPDATE`s are all missing `SET` clauses. I believe you're mixing `UPDATE` and `INSERT INTO`, don't you? The correct way to write this would be either joins or subqueries. But it's hard to guess which column belongs to which table as they are neither qualified nor did you post the schema. Therefore giving a more specific answer is difficult. So please post the DDL (`CREATE TABLE` statements) of all the tables.

Comment: Also, a common question, that arises in such cases, do you really need to physically update all the data or can it be retrieved querying? It looks a lot like your `widget_dash_*` could be just realized as views querying `global_summary`. If I interpret that right, `global_summary` contains some versions of some data depending on the time? And the `widget_dash_*` should contain the latest portion of them?

Comment: Thanks sticky bit, I have updated above.

Comment: Add semicolons (`;`) between statements!